# Set active item in owlCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel-2

I have a owl carousel with 3 items, the carousel displays one item per page.
Inside each item I have html inputs.

I want to programmatically change the active item so I can make focus on input inside it.

Here is the initial configuration:

```
var owl = $("#selector").owlCarousel({
    slideSpeed: 300,
    paginationSpeed: 400,
    items: 1,
    itemsDesktop: false,
    itemsDesktopSmall: false,
    itemsTablet: false,
    itemsMobile: false,
    dots: false,
    touchDrag: false,
    mouseDrag: false
});
```

And the html looks like this:

```
<div id="selector" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
        <input type="text" name="name1" id="input1">
     </div>

    <div class="item">
        <input type="text" name="name2" id="input2">
     </div>

    <div class="item">
        <input type="text" name="name3" id="input3">
     </div>
</div>
```

For example: if I want to make focus on input3, I have to set the current page to 3 and then set the focus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`to.owl.carousel` the event goes to a position.

**Parameter**: `[position, speed]`

```
$("#selector").trigger("to.owl.carousel", [2, 1])
```

As per the events docs: http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html

Comment: tyler thanks for your answer. It worked with a minimal change. `$("#carousel").trigger("to.owl.carousel", [2, 1, true]);`.

I found it at [this issue on Github](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/166#issuecomment-46452372).

Comment: @anyeloamt great, I've updated my answer to reflect it.  Feel free to mark as correct so that others searching around will know you got an answer

Comment: @tyler The Link in the answer is down. Meanwhile: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html

what does the true represent?